# Scrolling without draging scroll bar in windows tablet using xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

I am developing a xamarin.forms application(Android, iOS and UWP) with Xamarin 4.4. In which I am using a Listview to populate data in it. I tested the app in android and the scrolling is working perfectly in it. While testing the UWP in Windows 10(version 1909)[Point of Sale Machine], the scrolling is not working like in android. I have to use the Scroll Bars for scrolling.

Is there any extra settings, I have to do to accomplish the same in UWP? or It is not possible to achieve the same in UWP.

this is the code, I am using

```
<ListView x:Name="lstPOSItems"
          HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
          VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
          ItemsSource="{Binding AddedItems}"
          SeparatorVisibility="None"
          Visual="Material"
          ItemTapped="lstPOSItems_ItemTapped">
          <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <ViewCell>
                <Frame HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                       VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                       BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                       Padding="0">
                  <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        Margin="3">
                    <Label Text="{Binding OrderDetails, Mode=TwoWay}"
                           IsVisible="{Binding OrderDetails,Converter={StaticResource StringToBoolConverter}}"
                           HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                           HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                           VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                  </Frame>
                </ViewCell>
              </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
          </ListView>
```

Comment: What happens if you wrap all of it inside a ScrollView?

Comment: One should not put a ListView in a ScrollView as the scrolling can get confused between the two scrolling views. That said, I am not seeing the described issue 
 when following the code example.

Comment: @Gireesh, I agree with jgoldberger's opinion, I try your code in Android and UWP, but I don't find any issue, so can you provide some screenshot about your issue here?